# Neo4j input limit

Tags: neo4j, dataset, cypher

I have large amount of movies and keywords related. I parsed a data text file with keywords to create nodes for every keyword. It is about 160k keywords, so 160k lines of create queries. I procedurally created text file with these queries. Then I browsed to localhost where I can manage my database. I dropped this file with that huge query there and executed it.

After few seconds it returned an error:

> Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure

I think it's due to size of query. I picked just few lines and then execute. Nodes were created. But when I picked about 500 lines, same error was returned. With about 450 lines it runs fine.

1. Is there any way to execute such large queries in Neo4j? You understand that copy-paste 160k lines by about 450 lines at once is crazy even if that it is just a part of my database (need also movies and relationships).
2. Is Neo4j(free version) limited in data stored in database?
3. How should I manage my database? Is it ok to use that tool in browser or should I use some programming language to access database? If so what would be best way and how to do that?

Comment: You should at least a bit concerned trying to paste 160k of create statements into a web application input field

Comment: @MichaelHunger I don't really know what do you mean. Sorry my English isn't very good so maybe I don't understand meaning of your comment. Anyway I think, it's a database so it should take large amount of data if somebody want to build large dataset. Of course it is web application but I don't care of time of uploading, I just care about being it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Best practice for this kind of operation is to convert the data to be imported into csv format and then apply the `LOAD CSV` command from Neo4j browser.
2. Neo4j community edition has the same capabilities in terms of capacity.
3. Most people use the Neo4j browser as a developer tool to build their cypher queries. The queries then go into an application on whatever stack you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much for fast reply. I saw something about CSV. Do you have some hint how to import .txt into CSV? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I made CSV from that file now. But, it should look like an table where one column is one property and other is other property? Am I right? So making CSV from .txt where are lines as: CREATE (:Keyword {word:"western"}); isn't really proper :D I will do It later, Thank you very much for now.

Comment: @Gondil - please don't ask additional questions in comments - this will soon turn into a discussion, which is not what comments are intended for. You might want to post a separate question.

Comment: Loading a CSV is well-documented on the Neo4j site. And it's a separate question. Just remember this isn't a discussion forum. Stefan already posted a link to the material, which you can read, and then post a new question about if you can't figure it out.